# SQL need to separate results by "before" and "after" date using a third table

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the situation: I have tables where relevant rows are...

```
contact
-- contact_id

event
-- event_id
-- event_group_id

groups
-- group_id

groupmember
-- group_id
-- contact_id

attendance
-- contact_id
-- group_id
-- event_id
-- timestamp (current timestamp)



//Query the database for group members 
$result = mysql_query(
"SELECT contact.contact_id, contact.first, contact.last, 
  contact.home_phone, contact.mobile_phone, contact.email, contact.address, 
  contact.city, contact.state, contact.zip 
FROM contact 
INNER JOIN groupmember ON contact.contact_id = groupmember.contact_id 
WHERE groupmember.group_id = '$groupid' 
ORDER BY last
    ");
```

What I would like to do is trim those results by checking the table named "attendance" and only showing those results that have attended an event sponsored by the group '$group' in the last 6 months.

Then, after those results are shown, to generate another list at the bottom of the page showing those contacts who are 'inactive' because the last time they attended an event sponsored by '$group' was over 6 months ago. 
I would assume another WHERE statement would have to be appended with an INNER JOIN with the attendance table, but I'm not even sure that can be done.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you join over to the attendance table as well?

If you do, GROUP BY contact_id and grab the MAX(timestamp).  You can use that to answer your first question:

```
 MAX(timestamp) >= datesub(now(), interval 6 month)
```

and your second:

```
 MAX(timestamp) < datesub(now(), interval 6 month)
```

Note that your second question asks for people who have previously attended an event, so you're guaranteed that a row exists in the attendance table.  If you had not stated that, and it would be possible for a contact to not have an attendance record, you'd need to use an OUTER JOIN.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you.  That was so obvious I don't know why I didn't think of that.